# C array of pointers on string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Well I don't work a lot with a pointers but now I get confused. I'm trying create array of pointers at strings (in this example just 2 pointers).

```
    char str[120];
    char* st[2];
    int i=1;
    while (fgets(str,120,f)) {

    printf("%s",str);
    st[i]=&str;

    i++;
    if (i==3)
        break;
}
for (i=1;i<=2;i++) {
    puts(st[i]);
}
```

*warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]*

so can you help me understand all this situation with pointers on a strings. Please

Comment: `st[i]` is a `char*`, or a pointer to a character. `&str` is a `char(*)[120]`, or a pointer to an array of 120 characters. Notice those are different.

Comment: so I need change &str to str, when I did it I got this: 12
1211
��!��
��!��

Comment: `int i=0;`..`st[i]=strdup(str);`.. `if (i==2)`.. `for (i=0;i<2;i++) {`

Comment: The second thing you're doing is that you're using `st[1]` and `st[2]`. `st[1]` is the second element in st. `st[2]` is the third element in st, which is two elements long, and therefore doesn't have a third element.

Comment: @immibis now i got it, it is very interesting that indexing is very important for pointeer. it will be good if you will write an answer with how array of pointer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays always use 0-based index.

for example:

```
int my_arr[] = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
```

means that the array my_arr has 6 elements starting from index 0 till 6-1 (5). So, an N element array will have its indices from 0 to N-1. Also, note that my_arr by itself is also a pointer to the array.

define a int pointer:

```
int *iPtr = my_arr; // note that we do not use &my_arr here. my_arr is already a pointer to the array it defined.
```

or

```
int *iPtr;
iPtr= my_arr;
```

they are the same.

[image: Array and Pointer in Memory]

In the figure, the box represent the values and their addresses are written besides the boxes.

When you iterate over the array using variable `i` as index. You basically do the following indirectly:

```
i = 0
my_arr[i]
```

is same as

```
my_arr[0]
```

is same as

```
*(my_arr + 0)
```

is same as (substitute the value of box named my_arr)

```
*(20014000+0)
```

The * operator gets you the value at the address `0x20014000` in this example which is `10`.

The above operation is also same as

```
iPtr[0] or *(iPtr+0)
```

Look at the box named `iPtr`, it also contains the same value `0x20014000`.

Now lets define an array of pointers:

```
int *myptr_arr[3];
int varA = 25;
int varB = 34;
int varC = 67;

myptr_arr[0] = &varA; // note that varA is not a pointer, to get its address use &
myptr_arr[1] = &varB; // note that varB is not a pointer, to get its address use &
myptr_arr[2] = &varC; // note that varC is not a pointer, to get its address use &
```

[image]

once again, when you write `myptr_arr[0]` it translates to

```
*(myptr_arr + 0)

*(20152000 + 0)
```

which will get you `0x20162000` i.e. the value of box named `[0]` = the address of `varA`. Now to get the value at this address, you need to dereference it with `*` operator.

```
*myptr_arr[0]
```

which is same as `* ( *(myptr_arr + 0) )`
which is same as `*(0x20162000)`
which is the value of box `varA`

Please see : [Example usage of pointers](https://github.com/Mrunmoy/HelloPointers)